# Scala Extractor with Argument

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is there a syntax in Scala that allows extractors to take a customization argument?  This example is a bit contrived.  Suppose I have a binary search tree on integers, and I want to match on the current node if its value is divisible by some custom value.

Using F# active patterns, I can do the following:

```
type Tree =
    | Node of int * Tree * Tree
    | Empty  

let (|NodeDivisibleBy|_|) x t =
    match t with
    | Empty -> None
    | Node(y, l, r) -> if y % x = 0 then Some((l, r)) else None

let doit = function
    | NodeDivisibleBy(2)(l, r) -> printfn "Matched two: %A %A" l r
    | NodeDivisibleBy(3)(l, r) -> printfn "Matched three: %A %A" l r
    | _ -> printfn "Nada"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let t10 = Node(10, Node(1, Empty, Empty), Empty)
    let t15 = Node(15, Node(1, Empty, Empty), Empty)

    doit t10
    doit t15

    0
```

In Scala, I can do something similar, but not quite what I want:

```
sealed trait Tree
case object Empty extends Tree
case class Node(v: Int, l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree

object NodeDivisibleBy {
  def apply(x: Int) = new {
    def unapply(t: Tree) = t match { 
      case Empty => None
      case Node(y, l, r) => if (y % x == 0) Some((l, r)) else None
    }
  }
}

def doit(t: Tree) {
  // I would prefer to not need these two lines.
  val NodeDivisibleBy2 = NodeDivisibleBy(2)
  val NodeDivisibleBy3 = NodeDivisibleBy(3)
  t match { 
    case NodeDivisibleBy2(l, r) => println("Matched two: " + l + " " + r)
    case NodeDivisibleBy3(l, r) => println("Matched three: " + l + " " + r)
    case _ => println("Nada")
  }
}

val t10 = Node(10, Node(1, Empty, Empty), Empty)
val t15 = Node(15, Node(1, Empty, Empty), Empty)

doit(t10)
doit(t15)
```

It would be great if I could do:

```
case NodeDivisibleBy(2)(l, r) => println("Matched two: " + l + " " + r)
case NodeDivisibleBy(3)(l, r) => println("Matched three: " + l + " " + r)
```

but this is a compile time error: '=>' expected but '(' found.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

From [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> ```
>    SimplePattern ::= StableId ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’
> ```
>
> An extractor pattern *x(p1, ..., pn)* where *n ≥ 0* is of the same
>   syntactic form as a constructor pattern. However, instead of a case
>   class, the stable identifier *x* denotes an object which has a member
>   method named `unapply` or `unapplySeq` that matches the pattern.

and:

> A *stable identifier* is a path which ends in an identifier.

i.e., not an expression like `NodeDivisibleBy(2)`.

So no, this isn't possible in any straightforward way in Scala, and personally I think that's just fine: having to write the following (which by the way I'd probably define in the `NodeDivisibleBy` object and import):

```
val NodeDivisibleBy2 = NodeDivisibleBy(2)
val NodeDivisibleBy3 = NodeDivisibleBy(3)
```

is a small price to pay for the increased readability of not having to decipher arbitrary expressions in the case clause.

Answer (score 4):

As Travis Brown has noted, it's not really possible in scala.

What I do in that scenario is just separating the decomposition from the test with a guard and an alias.

```
val DivisibleBy = (n: Node, x: Int) => (n.v % x == 0) 

def doit(t: Tree) = t match { 
    case n @ Node(y, l, r) if DivisibleBy(n,2) => println("Matched two: " + l + " " + r)
    case n @ Node(y, l, r) if DivisibleBy(n,3) => println("Matched three: " + l + " " + r)
    case _ => println("Nada")
}
```

Defining a separate `DivisibleBy` is obviously complete overkill in this simple case, but may help readability in more complex scenarios in a similar way as F# active patterns do.

You could also define divisibleBy as a method of Node and have:

```
case class Node(v: Int, l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree {
    def divisibleBy(o:Int) = (v % o)==0
}

def doit(t: Tree) = t match { 
    case n @ Node(y, l, r) if n divisibleBy 2 => println("Matched two: " + l + " " + r)
    case n @ Node(y, l, r) if n divisibleBy 3 => println("Matched three: " + l + " " + r)
    case _ => println("Nada")
}
```

which I think is more readable (if more verbose) than the F# version

Answer (score 2):

Bind together the case class, predicate and arguments, then match on the result as usual.

```
case class Foo(i: Int)

class Testable(val f: Foo, val ds: List[Int])

object Testable {
  def apply(f: Foo, ds: List[Int]) = new Testable(f, ds)
  def unapply(t: Testable): Option[(Foo, List[Int])] = {
    val xs = t.ds filter (t.f.i % _ == 0)
    if (xs.nonEmpty) Some((t.f, xs)) else None
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val f = Foo(100)

  Testable(f, List(3,5,20)) match {
    case Testable(f, 3 :: Nil)  => println(s"$f matched three")
    case Testable(Foo(i), 5 :: Nil) if i < 50
                                => println(s"$f matched five")
    case Testable(f, ds)        => println(s"$f matched ${ds mkString ","}")
    case _                      => println("Nothing")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but there is a scalac plugin providing syntax `~(extractorWithParam(p), bindings)`, with all safety from compilation: https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte/tree/master/scalac-plugin#match-component

Comment: As per the StackOverflow ["How to not be a spammer" guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), you must disclose your affiliation to the Acolyte project. "The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Answer (score -1):

As I know answer is no.

I also use the previous way for this case.